# Compile-time shared library symbols in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, swc

Our Flash project has the following structure. Two FLA files with graphical assets (symbols), imported into a pure AS3 code project using SWCs.

[image]

There are some symbols that are used in both ui.fla and login.fla, so we'd like to put them in a shared library, like so.

[image]

The catch is that we don't want to use shared.fla's symbols in e.g. ui.fla's code, but in the authoring environment, so that we can drag symbols from shared.fla into ui.fla's symbols (without copying). Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharing assets can be possible via `Remote Shared Library` (RSL).

*But please, be careful: I haven't seen this way in production, it was only my experiments some years ago.*

Here is an example:

1. Create document, that will contain shared assets. Let it have names 'shared_lib'
2. Create some symbol. Prepare it for RSL:

   - In Flash IDE choose Library->your symbol(right click)->Properties...
   - Select `Export for ActionScript` & `Export in frame 1`, type the name of symbol
   - Select `Export for runtime sharing`. Type the name of that swf: 'shared_lib.swf'
   - `OK`
   - `Publish` it to SWF and SWC

So, now we have our library. Lets create some asset, that will use it

1. Create another document, lets call it 'mainui'.
2. Return to the 'shared_lib', select in `Library` exported symbol, `CTRL + C` (or right click, copy)
3. Return to just created 'mainui', paste to `Library`.
4. Create some other symbol, export it for ActionScript and place our imported symbol into it
5. Compile it, export to SWC, SWF.

At this step, we have `shared_lib.swf`, `shared_lib.swc` and `mainui.swc`. In out `mainui` we can work with external asset as well. You can create another assets in the same way.

Lets talk about project settings, that will use our assets.

So, what we have exactly at the moment? `Mainui.swc` has the symbol, that contains another **'virtual'** symbol. If you just try to load `mainui.swf` in browser with some profiler, you'll see, that at first it loads `mainui.swf`, then it loads `shared_lib.swf`.

But if you try to create some project and include `mainui.swc`, you'll get the error with undefined symbol, because all that have mainui - is just virtual reference to symbol from shared_lib.

To resolve it, you must **completely** include `shared_lib.swc` in your project. In this case, you'll have:

- via **library-path directive**: optionaly included `mainui.swc`
- via **include-libraries directive**: completely included `shared_lib.swc`

Now, it will work.

Hope, it will be helpful.

Comment: Yes, it works. We tried this before, but got stuck on having to enter URLs, which made no sense. But apparently if you make sure the assets are already available at runtime (by a merged SWC) they don't get loaded again, so the URL may be a mock value.

Comment: As I understand, compiled swc will never trigger load any remote data, in any case.

Comment: No, they don't, but the point is that compiling in an SWC containing runtime shared resources prevents an attempt for loading them at runtime (which would fail), since they are already present.